# How to make it so bash runs instead of asking where to run upon selection from file navigator

Tags: linux, bash, debian, linux-mint

When I double-click on bash files on Linux Mint a pop-up appears querying whether I want to run in terminal, display, run, or cancel. I was wondering, how do I make it so for this particular bash file it runs without this pop-up (preferably without the presentation of the terminal). Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it with the bash script directly, you will need to create a .desktop file for it instead. For example, if your bash script is saved as `/home/cenoc/bin/script.sh`, create a file called `script.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My script
Comment=Describe your script here
Exec=/home/cenoc/bin/script.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Then, double click on `script.desktop` and your script should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it's more a security reason, as well as convenience.
I wouldn't want to mistakenly run the file when I just want to edit it.
If you need to run the file at boot I would use one of your start up scripts.

Comment: I would understand the security fear, but I just want a layman user to be able to come up to this and double click without having something pop-up like this complicating the arrangement. I could always write-up and compile something to do what the bash file is doing, but was hoping I can just use the bash file and change the icon.

Comment: Well it depends on what file manager you're using as well. Some will have different behaviour. Example for caja, native in Mint afaik.    Go to Edit>Preferences>Behaviour    Under Executable text files you have 3 options. Select which one you need.  The first option should work for your case.    Should also work in nemo as well.